# javascript buttons firing another button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I want to create a `button` that creates another `button`. The other `button` get an `id` attribute by counting from 1 to infinity. **This functionality should done on all buttons (original button and the news).**

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.type = "button"
btn.value = "button"
btn.id = "btn_rv"
body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: Provided code will work fine except(`document.body.appe..`). Maybe it will not under the circumstances you are executing it..

Comment: its working. i just want to create a button that "create another button" named btn_rv_1 <-- and when i click it "it will fire another button anmed btn_rv_1_1"

Comment: Your question does not way so ? Update it accordingly to understand the issue..

Comment: i cant add undersocre on the question sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function create_another_button(elm) {
  var counter = parseInt(elm.getAttribute('data-counter'));
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerText = elm.id + '_' + counter;
  button.id = elm.id + '_' + counter;
  button.setAttribute('data-counter', '1');
  button.setAttribute('onclick','create_another_button(this)');
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  elm.setAttribute('data-counter', ++counter)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_rv" onclick="create_another_button(this)" data-counter="1">Main Button</button>
```

http://jsbin.com/tuwoxe/edit?html,css,js

Comment: no sir, i mean when i click the button it fires another button that have id btn_rv_1_1 and so on

Comment: I just was updated my answer. Is that what you looking for?

Comment: sir, can you please add that when i click the second button it will fire another button that named id "btn_rv_1_1"

Comment: and so on but its in the id not the name itself

Comment: I don't understand. Can you clarify this? When I click on the `Main Button` what should happen?  When I click on the added button (`btn_rv_1_1`) for example, what should happen then? Please explain all scenarios of all the buttons clicks.

Comment: when you click the main button named by ID btn_rv << it will fire a second button name by ID btn_rv_1 << and when you click the second button name by ID btn_rv_1 << it will fire a button name by ID btn_rv_1_1 BUT when you click the main button again << it will fire the next button named by ID btn_rv_2

Comment: sir it mean clicking the button is just adding underscore and +1number on it

Comment: Thank you so much sir! thats the answer i was look for. :)

Comment: My pleasure. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer so it will help to other people.

Answer (score 0):

I do not get the use case, but this should be what you are looking for:

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
var countBtn;
btn.type = "button";
btn.value = "button";
btn.id = "btn_rv";
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (!countBtn){
    countBtn = document.createElement("input");
    countBtn.type = "button";
    countBtn.value = 0;
    countBtn.id = "btn_rv";
    document.body.appendChild(countBtn);
  }
  else{
    countBtn.value++;
  }

}, false);
```

Check it out at https://jsfiddle.net/ugyknfc0/

Comment: no sir, i mean when i click the button it fires another button that have id btn_rv_1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fire another button , try this code

```
<input type="button" 
   id="BtnId" 
   onclick="fireButton();addButton();" />
```

Function 1 for firing the Button

```
function fireButton() 
{
   document.getElementById('btn_rv_1').click()
}
```

Function 2 for adding the Button

```
function addButton()
 {
   var element = document.createElement("input");

//Assign different attributes to the element.
  element.setAttribute("type", type);
  element.setAttribute("value", type);
  element.setAttribute("name", type);


  var place= document.getElementById("SpanID");

 //Append the element in page (in span).
  place.appendChild(element);
 }
```

In HTML

```
<span id="SpanID">&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: yes i know that. but the id must be btn_rv_1 and when i click it, it must create another button btn_rv_1_1

Comment: for that you can call two different functions also like onClick="fire();addbutton()"

Comment: but its not a best way but you can easily achieve your req

Comment: pls give me code i am beginner in programming thanks(this is my first question here)

Comment: Can you please explain your requiremnet properly in question

Comment: sir i mean clicking the same button add name id that have underscore and +1 to its id

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you can try this.

html

```
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <button id="button_1">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="func.js"></script>
</body>
```

func.js

```
var bid = 2;

document.getElementById("button_1").addEventListener("click", function () {
    add_button(bid);
    add_event_listener(bid);
    bid += 1;
});

function add_button(button_id) {
    var div = document.getElementById("top");
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<button id='button_" + button_id + "'>Button " + button_id + "</button>";
}

function add_event_listener(button_id) {
    document.getElementById("button_" + button_id).addEventListener("click", function () {
        add_button(bid);
        add_event_listener(bid);
        ++bid;
    });
}
```